# Бесплатный хостинг с поддержкой Python и PostgreSQL для образовательных целей

Tags: python, postgresql, хостинг

Интересует разместить проект на Python с использованием PostgreSQL на бесплатном хостинге на примере [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) (но в нем платная поддержка PostgreSQL).

Может есть варианты подобные этому [тарифу "Образовательный"](https://masterhost.ru/service/hosting/virtual/special/unix/edu/) на другом бесплатном хостинге с поддержкой Python 2.7 и PostgreSQL 9.6?

Comment: Для образовательных целей чем локалхост не угодил?

Comment: @andreymal локалхост не получится протестировать в реальных условиях, со случайными пользователями из интернета в течении более-менее длительного времени.

Comment: Может быть [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)?

Comment: На амазоне можно взять виртуальный сервер на год свободного пользования