# Как опубликовать файл server.py для удаленного доступа

Tags: python, развертывание, heroku

Хочу опубликовать файл `server.py` для удаленного доступа так, что бы я мог на него сослаться в своей программе, `server.py` произвел запрограммированную обработку сохранив данные в БД, а я получил результаты вычислений.

Файл `server.py` опубликован на GitHub.

Еще мне необходимо запустить `server.py` перед началом передачи данных (могу скомпилировать файл в виде `server.exe`, но предварительный запуск избежать не получается).

Рассматривал возможность опубликовать файл на [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) используя бесплатный аккаунт, но там нет поддержки используемой у меня `PostgreSQL`.

Еще смотрю возможности хостинга [`Heroku`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/) но не могу разобраться, как запустить приложение `server.py` (или `server.exe`).

Как опубликовать и запустить файл `server.py` на бесплатном хостинге с поддержкой `PostgreSLQ`?

Comment: Похоже на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593798/

Comment: @gil9red там я ищу бесплатный хостинг, а здесь надеюсь получить помощь по публикации на каком-нибудь другом хостинге или в частности на `Heroku`

Comment: тут вы тоже ищите бесплатный хостинг `Как опубликовать и запустить файл server.py на бесплатном хостинге` :)

Comment: каждый DBaaS, IaaS, PaaS, etc имеет инструкции о том как развернуть сервис именно на них. Инструкции для Scalingo будут отличаться от инструкций для ElephantSQL, Google App Engine будет отличаться от MS Azure итд. Heroku эта одна из простых и хорошо документированных опций. [Начните здесь (с самого просто кода)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction) и продолжайте пока не упрётесь в шаг, который самостоятельно не получается выполнить, тогда задайте вопрос именно об этом шаге (что ожидали получить, что вместо этого происходит, подробно).